# copy values from one file to another when condition is true

Tags: perl

I have two tables. I want to copy values from one file to another if a certain condition is met. This is how everything looks like

Table 1

```
C1    C2    C3
1     a     b
3     e     f
```

Table 2

```
C1    C2    ...  ...    C7    C8 ...
      1          
      2
      3
```

Table 2 should become like this:

```
C1    C2    ...  ...    C7    C8 ...
      1                       x=b  
      2          
      3                       x=f
```

So if the values of C1 (table1) and C2 (table2) are the same, then the values of C3 of table 1 should be put in columns C8 of table 2. The new values in C8 should all start with "x=" followed by the corresponding value from table 1

This is the script I'm using so far to open my data

```
my $data1 = $ARGV[0];
my $data2 = $ARGV[1];

unless ($data1) {
    print "Enter filename:\n";
    $data1 = <STDIN>;
    chomp $data1;}
open(DATA1,'<',$data1) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";

unless ($data2) {
    print "Enter filename:\n";
    $data2 = <STDIN>;
    chomp $data2;}
open(DATA2,'<',$data2) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";

while (<DATA1>) {
    my @columns = split /\s+/;
    next  if /^\s*C/;
      # I'm doing some transformations here so that my input DATA1 has the format of  table 1 in my example
    }

foreach $c1(sort {$a<=>$b} keys %info ) {
    print $c1, "\t", 
      join(',',@{$info{$c1}->{variant}}), "\t", 
      join(',',@{$info{$c1}->{frequency}}), "\n";
# so $c1 is actually how table 1 in my example looks like
}

my %hash;

while($c1){
     my @columns = split;
     $hash{$columns[0]} = [$columns[2]];
     }

while (<DATA2>) {
     my @columns = split;               
     $columns[7] = @{ $hash{ $columns[0] } }[2] if exists $hash{ $columns[0] };
     print "\t", join (@columns), "\n";
     }
```

This is the script with the solution @choroba provided. However something must be wrong, since I don't get any output on the screen.

And how can I add the statement "x=" when copying the values?

Comment: Does table 2 always contain only the same first 3 columns of table 1 or could table 2 also contain e.g. columns C1, C4, C6?

Comment: I just edited my file to make it look more like the real situation.

Answer (score 2):

Use a hash to remember the first file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my ($data1, $data2) = @ARGV;

open my $T1, '<', $data1 or die $!;
my %hash;
while (<$T1>) {
    my @fields = split;
    $hash{$fields[0]} = [ @fields[ 1, 2 ] ];
}

open my $T2, '<', $data2 or die $!;
while (<$T2>) {
    my @fields = split;
    @fields[1, 2] = @{ $hash{ $fields[0] } }[0, 1] if exists $hash{ $fields[0] };
    say join "\t", @fields;
}
```

Comment: @user1987607: You are probably using very old version of Perl. Remove the `feature` line and use `print` instead of `say`, just add `"\n"` at the end of each output line.

Comment: Now I get a syntax error near print `print join ("\t", @fields), "\n";`

Comment: The syntax error is fixed. I've changed the things you proposed in my original post. Could you take a look at my script, since there is still something wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash for the first file to do this:

```
my %columns1;
while (<DATA1>) {
    my @c = split /\s+/;
    $columns1{$c[0]} = [ @c ];
    next  if /^\s*C/;}
my %columns2;
while (<DATA2>) {
     my @c = split /\s+/;
     if (defined $columns1{$c[0]}) {
        $c[1] = $columns1{$c[0]}[1];
        $c[2] = $columns1{$c[0]}[2];
     }
     $columns2{$c[0]} = [ @c ];
}
```